# a word/phrase for 贪小便宜的

Tags: word-choice

Need a word to describe someone who doesn't need the product but buys it because he/she has a coupon.

I would use 贪小便宜的 , but what is a proper equivalent in English

Have seen the posts
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308698/a-word-for-a-person-who-never-overpays, still couldn't decide which is the best one.

Note：I am looking for the English equivalent of 贪小便宜的，rather than a Chinese synonym.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 葛朗台, which is actually the Chinese translation of the main character's name in *Eugénie Grandet*, a novel by French author Honoré de Balzac.

A less witty one would be 小气鬼，which is equivalent to the English penny-pincher or cheapskate.

Comment: I believe OP was asking for an English translation rather than a Chinese one but you've included **penny-pincher** and **cheapskate** so that might suffice.

Comment: Just want to say while penny-pincher and cheapskate fits well, 小气鬼 is not really a good translation for these words.  小气鬼 is usually referred to someone narrow-minded

Answer (score 1):

> Need a word to describe someone who doesn't need the product but buys
>   it because he/she has a coupon.

You want 1 word, in Chinese (or English?), for a compulsive redeemer of coupons.

Such a word does not exist.

I would like to redeem this coupon.
我想使用这张优惠券。

If he has a coupon for something, he will buy it.
如果他有优惠券，他就会买东西的。

a compulsive consumer: 一个强迫症消费者

thrift: 节约, 节俭
thrifty: 节俭的

a compulsive saver: 一个强迫症节俭者。

A person who has to use coupons if he has them might then be:

a compulsive redeemer of coupons: 一个强迫症使用优惠券者???

She just has to use coupons.
她强迫性地使用优惠券。

Wasn't there a Hongkong film "消费狂“ about a woman who could not stop buying?

Comment: Thanks, I guess " a compulsive redeemer of coupons" is something I am looking for unless there is a more accurate but simple alternative.

Answer (score 0):

贪小便宜的=
1. a cheap ass
2. niggard
3. (likes to) take (petty) advantages of (others)

Answer (score 0):

贪小便宜的 basically means a stingy person or cheapskate. I think this is a pretty good description.